# indexing vs normalization when optimizing for read speed

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

Having an architecture discussion with a coworker and we need to find an answer for this. Given a set of millions of data points that look like:

```
data =
[{
    "v" : 1.44,
    "tags" : {
        "account" : {
            "v" : "1055",
            "name" : "Circle K"
        }
        "region" : "IL-East"
    }
}, {
    "v" : 2.25,
    "tags" : {
        "account" : {
            "v" : "1055",
            "name" : "Circle K"
        }
        "region" : "IL-West"
    }
}]
```

and that we need to query on the fields in the tags collection (e.g. where account.name == "Circle K"), would there be any speed benefit to normalizing the account field to this:

```
accounts =
[{
    _id : 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011,
    v: "1055",
    name : "Circle K"
}]

data =
[{
    "v" : 1.44,
    "tags" : {
        "account" : 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011
        "region" : "IL-East"
    }
}, {
    "v" : 2.25,
    "tags" : {
        "account" : 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011
        "region" : "IL-West"
    }
}]
```

I suspect I'll have to build 2 db's for this and just see what the speed looks like. The question is, is mongo better at querying on BSON IDs vs. strings? The db in question will be about 1:10 write vs. read.

Comment: I wouldn't suspect an important different between the two, given the way a B-tree stores the keys.

Comment: @WiredPrairie my suspicion as well; we need to max out performance so I'll have to test both -- actually I think the normalized version may be slower, since it's two queries vs. one

Comment: Definitely it will be somewhat slower to do two queries. I was commenting only on your `_id` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing here is to make sure that you have enough RAM for your working set. That includes the space for the "tags.account.name" index and the expected query result set.

As for the key size. You use ObjectID-as-string above, which you should not do. Leave the real ObjectIDs in as their size is quite a bit smaller. If you really have a lot of small documents, then you might even want to think about shorting your field names as well.

Comment: "You use ObjectID-as-string above, which you should not do" -- just did that because I didn't know off the top of my head what those looked like in JSON

Comment: I agree, you need to ensure an adequate amount of RAM on your MongoDB server, and also that the 'tags.account.name' index exists, that should be all you need for speedy lookups.